# is_tax is failing me and can't figure out the solution

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom post type ("Products") for a site I'm developing, along with corresponding custom categories ("product_cats"). Certain products are categorized with "BC Buy Local" as well as their product family ("Rice Wrap" for example).

So far everything's working great, I can display what product famlies I want, and I can even call up ALL the products categorized as "BC Buy Local" with this URL:

http://localhost/hons.com/wordpress/product-type/bc-buy-local/

But I want these items to have an indication of their "BC Buy Local" status, wherever they appear - and they are all members of other product families, i.e. categories. But when being displayed via their so-called "family" category, it seems that these items do not also get flagged as being in the "BC Buy Local" category. So, the list of products here:

http://localhost/hons.com/wordpress/product-type/rice-wrap/

...ignores my attempt to add an indication of their BC Buy Local category by adding this code after the product name, in the loop:

`<?php if ( is_tax ('product_cats', 'bc-buy-local') ) { 
    echo 'BC Buy Local';
} ?>`

I've located much discussion of the limitations of "is_tax" here on StackOverflow, but - so far - no indication of how to address this issue. Apparently i need to use a combination of "is_tax" and "has_term" but I can't figure out how to do this.

It seems it should be so simple... can anyone advise?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: `is_tax` checks if you are on a particular archive, `has_term` checks if a post has a particular term. it seems you want just `has_term`.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I had high hopes for has_term but when I use it instead, I just get no results at all under any circumstances, or so it seems. I assume my code would otherwise be the same? I.E. passing the taxonomy name and the term?

Comment: `has_term` needs a post object to operate on, as it pertains to specific posts, so *where* you try to use it is very important!

Comment: I'll study up on it and hopefully get it working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Milo, it was "has_term" that I needed. I found some VERY complex "answers" elsewhere that seemed to be addressing my situation, but am glad it was just a matter of using the right function.

One thing that tripped me up for a while: has_term takes the specific term, THEN the taxonomy as arguments - in that order. Unlike is_tax which seems to be in the OPPOSITE order. Yikes!